# How can we scrape the information inside the Javascript code in an instagram profile

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image]

I basically need the text preceding the word edge_followed_by.

I am using this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer 
import requests

res = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/dualipa/?hl=en')
res_text = res.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res_text,'lxml')
j = soup.select("script")
k = j
k = str(k)
print ('k')
```

Comment: have you tried looping through find_all.select("script"), then either use regex or convert object to JSON to retrieve edge_followed_by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re`/`json` module to parse the data. For example:

```
import re
import json
import requests


url = 'https://www.instagram.com/dualipa/?hl=en'

html_data = requests.get(url).text
data = json.loads(re.search(r'window\._sharedData = ({.*?});', html_data).group(1))

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count'])
```

Prints:

```
51310036
```

Comment: The fact that `['graphql']` is in there probably indicates the actual GraphQL API should be used instead